# jQuery remove checkbox based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following jQuery code:

**Working code**

```
if(report==='Group 1'){
    $('.spandiv').not(':eq(17)').remove();
}
```

This works fine and removes all checkboxes that don't equal `17`.  However what I am trying to do now is only remove certain checkboxes.

I have tried the following:

**Non-working code**

```
if(report==='Group 1'){
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(17)').remove();
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(16)').remove();
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(12)').remove();
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(6)').remove();
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(5)').remove();
    $('.spandiv').is(':eq(4)').remove();
}
```

I had assumed (clearly incorrectly) that this would work but it doesn't.  I am clearly doing something wrong and would appreciate any feedback/ assistance.

Comment: What about just `$('.spandiv:eq(17)').remove();`?

Comment: Oopss...clearly not a good day for me.  Thanks @j08691.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.is` method will return boolean `true` or `false` if the selector matches the selected element. You are looking for [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method or [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector (or [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in the last case):

```
$('.spandiv:eq(17)').remove();  // this is the same as
$('.spandiv').eq(17).remove();  // this and the same as
$('.spandiv').filter(':eq(17)').remove();  // this
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.spandiv:eq(17)').remove();
$('.spandiv:eq(16)').remove();
$('.spandiv:eq(12)').remove();
$('.spandiv:eq(6)').remove();
$('.spandiv:eq(5)').remove();
$('.spandiv:eq(4)').remove();
```

The `is` function is just a boolean check. You could replace it with `.filter()` or `.eq()` too:

```
$('.spandiv').eq(17).remove();
$('.spandiv').eq(16).remove();
$('.spandiv').eq(12).remove();
$('.spandiv').eq(6).remove();
$('.spandiv').eq(5).remove();
$('.spandiv').eq(4).remove();
```

Comment: Cheers for that, appreciated and for the further feedback.